# Installation issue : Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm getting this error when I try to access the base website url

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 19

I have deleted all the cache files with :

```
sudo rm generated/* var/cache/* di/* page_cache/*
```

The `setup:upgrade` run without issues. Any ideas where the error comes from ?

Comment: How did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ended up by fixing it doing this set of commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated
sudo docker-compose -p ctn run --rm tools php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo docker-compose -p ctn run --rm tools php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo docker-compose -p ctn run --rm tools php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo docker-compose -p ctn run --rm tools php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check custom module dependencies, make sure that module loaded in proper sequence app/etc/config.php also take the reference from this [blog](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034633551?_ga=2.188928238.473713690.1595259268-1433849325.1582475296)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this question looking for my own problem

The answer by OP did lead me to try with specifying the full php path instead of just calling `bin/magento` which, when that just worked, made me run `php -v` and aha!

In my case the default CLI php version used when I ran "bin/magento" had reverted to 7.2 when it needs to be 7.3 or up

Putting this here for the next person it happens to

Comment: My PHP version  7.3.2 getting the same error