# ReflectionException: Class Interceptor does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19

Tags: magento2, error, magento-framework

I'm getting this error on my homepage

> ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(235): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #5 /var/www/html/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framewo...') #6 {main}

So I tried to `setup:di:compile`

I had an error in `vendor/aheadworks/module-acr/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Directive.php`

It was using a missing class `use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;`

So I wrote that class in order to make the setup:di:compile works

> Compilation was started.
> Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 31 secs 380.0 MiB
> Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.

But I keep getting the same error on my main page, any ideas ?

Comment: If above error comes after any installation or updations?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I don't think so I didn't worked on this project since some time and I just wanted to go back to my active git branch which I were working the last time was on it. so I don't think there is any new installation here. But I'm working on a shared database so I might have something wrong ?

Comment: Oh wait I don't even remembered I had a similar issue some days ago : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317766/installation-issue-uncaught-reflectionexception-class-magento-framework-app-r

It's not the same error but I guess the fix will work anyway.

Comment: ok, otherwise disable this aheadworks/module-acr then check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So In fact the real problem here was due to a wrong docker installation (This project was runing under the same port as an other one).
Meanings all the commands were in fact running under the wrong project.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: Sadly I keep getting the error on di compile.  due to this module acr. But what I don't understand is that even if I disable the module if my config.php, he keeps trying to load it.

Comment: Then check, does any one call those files into the another module or somethnigs.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean generated folder.
Than:

- composer install
- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- bin/magento cache:flush

cheers

Comment: The strange thing is that I can't end di compile I'm getting `Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/aheadworks/module-acr/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Directive.php on line 21
` even considering the module `Aheadworks_Acr` is disabled

Comment: Ok, the magento 2 directives explain that changes cannot be made within the vendor folder except by using modules installed via composer or through the use of ece-tool patches. Based on this assumption, you can delete the contents of the vendor folder (first make a backup of that folder on another point) and then try to run the commands I told you above. @Claims

Comment: Sadly I keep getting this error on di compile even after deleting and re-generating all my vendor.

Comment: Ok I finally found what's was wrong here, it was not directly magento related, it was a docker issue, I had an other project running under the same port...meanings I didn't paid attention that my project didn't up correctly...meannings all the command I was running were not effective on the good project nor container !

Comment: all clear, update the issue and ... cheers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 2 steps:

**step 1:** disable this module we have identified as having an issue

```
php bin/magento module:disable Aheadworks_Acr
```

if the command above returns an error, go to `app/etc/config.php` and set the entry for this module to 0 manually

at this point, the module is disabled and It does seems this module is the culprit for some custom config that is not configured correctly somehow.

**step 2:**

The problem with config is they get to be part of the cache and they can be persistent. Because your issue has to do with config, I advise to clear `var/cache` folder manually and also if you use redis, do `redis-cli flushall`.

Once these 2 steps are complete, you should be able to run

```
php bin/magento cache:clean successfully
```

and your site should be back up.

Now, it may just be a syntax issue on your Aheadworks module and these guys have been on the market for long enough to say the module is likely working fine but somehow a syntax issue has cropped up..

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue due to permission

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```